# Android add data to custom layout and scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

in my application i have simple layout to filled by any data with class structure. after add items into that i want to add this layout into scroll view. adding layout to scrollview is successfull but i can not set data to custom layout. for example this is my custom layout to set data :

**tile.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp" android:minHeight="100dp" android:background="#eee">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/username"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Class data structure:**

```
public class SubjectStructure {
    public String    username;
    public String    topic;
    public String    description;
    public String    avatar;
    public String    sender;
    public Integer   grade;
    public Integer   type;
    public String    date;
}
```

now i want to fill tile.xml and add that into this below layout:

**fragment_home.xml:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#F1F1F1">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:id="@+id/scrollView1">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

my code is this :
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    scrollView = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById ( R.id.scrollView1 );

    for(SubjectStructure SS: G.subject_items){
        LinearLayout newLL = new LinearLayout( G.context );
        TextView newTV = new TextView( G.context );
        newTV.setText ( SS.topic );
        newLL.addView(newTV);

        LayoutInflater in =  (LayoutInflater) G.context.getSystemService(G.context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tile, null);
        scrollView.addView(view);
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

in this code i can add `tile.xml` to `fragment_home.xml` . but i can not setText `SS.topic` to `tile.xml`. `SS.topic` is not null and have data. how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code as follows:

```
for(SubjectStructure SS: G.subject_items){
    LayoutInflater in =  (LayoutInflater) G.context.getSystemService(G.context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tile, null);

    TextView textUserName=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
    textUserName.setText(SS.topic);

    scrollView.addView(view);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you are missing for sure is

```
 scrollView.addView(newLL);
```

to each iteration. About

```
LayoutInflater in =  (LayoutInflater) G.context.getSystemService(G.context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tile, null);
 scrollView.addView(view);
```

I am not sure its purpose. You create a new instance of `tile` at each iteration, but you do nothing on its content. On the minor side, you have already a LayoutInflater. You don't need to ask for one to the system at each iteration, use the one you get as parameter.